# C++ Class member is nullpointer

Tags: c++, class

I have a class (to render Text):

```
class TextRenderer {
public:
  TextRenderer();
  void RenderText(GLFWwindow *window, std::string text);
private:
  FT_Library ft;
  FT_Face face;
};
```

where I initialize the members `ft` and `face` in the constructor

```
TextRenderer::TextRenderer() {
    FT_Library ft;
    FT_Face face;

    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft));
    FT_New_Face(ft, "Assets/monospace.ttf", 0, &face);
    FT_Load_Char(face, 3, FT_LOAD_RENDER);

}
void TextRenderer::RenderText(GLFWwindow *window, std::string text) {
  FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph; //Shortcut
  ...
}
```

but when I want to use it like this:

```
  TextRenderer tr;
  while (cond) {
    tr.RenderText(consoleEngine.window, prefix + inp);
  }
```

I get an error stating

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this->face was nullptr.
```

for the first line of the `TextRenderer::RenterText` function.

I don't understand this. Isn't the variable face a member of the class TextRenderer and should thus have access to it?

Comment: Sorry, but you are not really initializing class members in the constructor, only some temporary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextRenderer::TextRenderer() {
    FT_Library ft;
    FT_Face face;

    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft));
    FT_New_Face(ft, "Assets/monospace.ttf", 0, &face);
    FT_Load_Char(face, 3, FT_LOAD_RENDER);
}
```

The `ft` and `face` variables you initialize are the local variables you declare in the constructor body. *Not* the member variables. You are shadowing those. The local variables will go out of scope / die once the ctor ends and your member variables will still be left uninitialised.

Also; do use the initialisation list rather than the ctor body.

Comment: And how would I initialize the member variables?

Comment: @Fl.pf. By not declaring local variables shadowing them. Or, ideally, just initializing them in-class or in the initialisation list.

Comment: Ok sorry, do you have a link for that? I don't know that much about OOP and classes (I only work with Fortran) and I don't know what shadowing is or how I would initialize a variable ?in-class? or what a initialization list is.

Comment: @Fl.pf. The best link I can give you in that case is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Fl.pf. See [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Shadowing is the concept of declaring a new object with the same name as an existing object such that the new one hides (shadows) the previous one. In this case, `FT_Library ft;` declares a variable called `ft` but it shadows `this->ft` (which is a totally different and distinct object).

Answer (score 2):

Those are function local variables in the constructor. They are different from the member variables of the class. As a consequence, the member variables remain uninitialized after the constructor returns.

Remove the lines:

```
FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;
```

Your function should be:

```
TextRenderer::TextRenderer() {
    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
    FT_New_Face(ft, "Assets/monospace.ttf", 0, &face);
    FT_Load_Char(face, 3, FT_LOAD_RENDER);
}
```

I suggest increasing the warning level of your compiler. The compiler will probably warn you that those variables, the function variables, shadow the member variables.

Comment: Worth a mention is that compiling with warnings would have given a *this variable shadows that variable* warning.

Comment: Then I would have to initialize and destruct ft and face in every iteration of the loop...

Comment: @Fl.pf., that's not obvious to me from the posted code.

Comment: I disagree. "Your function should be:": `TextRenderer::TextRenderer() :
    FT_Init_FreeType(&ft));
    FT_New_Face(ft, "Assets/monospace.ttf", 0, &face);
    FT_Load_Char(face, 3, FT_LOAD_RENDER) {}` - use the initialisation list, not the ctor body.

Comment: @Fl.pf. That's not true, and it's so far from being true that I suspect you're confused about some basics of OOP. Read your C++ textbook's description of how class member variables work again.

Comment: @Fl.pf. The important point is shadowing, your code could be written with or without an initialiser list. Your error was *redeclaring* `ft` and `face`. Did you not think it strange that it seemed you had to declare them twice?